# How to solve fast click on View?

Tags: android, onclick

```
findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
             startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

when i click the btn fast,i will call twice startActivity.

i found some app don't have that problem，like sina weibo.
it freeze activity until startActivity finish.

how to freeze User operation util System operation is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` while starting the activity

```
    intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This will have only have one activity in the stack, how quickly you press the button multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a boolean  eg boolean isToStartActivity;

```
  findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
         if(isToStartActivity){
            isToStartActivity = false
           startActivity(intent);
         }
    }
 }
```